# Why does plot not respect add = TRUE?

Tags: r

Why does R's base plot function do this? We have to use `points` or `lines`, which needs special code rather than using the `type` argument.

```
plot(1:10)
plot(10:1, add = TRUE)
Warning messages:
1: In plot.window(...) : "add" is not a graphical parameter
2: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : "add" is not a graphical parameter
3: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
```

Etc.

Many packages provide methods for (i.e. "override") plot and provide the obvious ability to plot(obj, add = TRUE) as long as `obj` is of the appropriate class. (Examples are `sp`, `raster`, `spatstat`.)

Is there any reason `plot.default` does not already?

EDIT: this was discussed at length here:

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2008-March/048628.html

DM effectively answers it here:

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2008-March/048650.html

Comment: you can use `add=TRUE` in `par`

Comment: @TylerRinker ?? `add` isn't a parameter in `?par`

Comment: `add` isn't an argument for `plot.default`. It is for `plot.function`, and maybe some others I'm unaware of. In the above example, you would use `points(...)`

Comment: @Gavin I was thinking `new=TRUE` as DWin demos.

Answer (score 16):

Because `plot.default` doesn't have an `add` argument

```
> args(plot.default)
function (x, y = NULL, type = "p", xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL, 
    log = "", main = NULL, sub = NULL, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, 
    ann = par("ann"), axes = TRUE, frame.plot = axes, panel.first = NULL, 
    panel.last = NULL, asp = NA, ...) 
NULL
```

Those other functions are **not** overriding `plot` but are providing their own *methods*, which do have an argument `add` because they were written that way. Personally, having grown up with using `points()` and `lines()` etc I don't find them much extra work and I would use them in preference to a `plot` method with an `add` argument, although we've written both ways in packages that I contribute to.

As to why `plot.default` doesn't have an `add` argument? You'd have to ask R Core, but I can suggest some reasons

1. `plot.default` is designed to generate an entire plot on the device
2. There already are `points()` and `lines()` etc so why duplicate?
3. `plot.default` is simpler code without code to handle `add`
4. Backwards compatibility with S/S-Plus

Comment: Plus 1 for the reasons.

Comment: "Override" and "provide methods for" are synonyms for me btw.

Comment: An additional reason is that it's a *good* thing that you can't reset xlim, ylim, etc. There are lots of arguments you don't want in the function that adds things to the plot.

Comment: But that's just another reason that simplifies the maintenance of the code and reflects the limitations of the graphics device, I think, not about the usefulness of the interface. Method writers don't avoid using the add option, because it's really useful to not have special names for different kinds of plot functions. To me, the ultimate reason is that "that's what S did", and no one has pushed. Using par(new = TRUE) is a reckless hack in my opinion, a very easy way to cause trouble.

Answer (score 15):

If `add=TRUE` is not provided (and you are using base graphics) then use `par(new=TRUE)` prior to the plot call. You will need to suppress the xlab, ylab and other stuff that might interfere or overlay existing annotation, and I did leave the ylab untouched to illustrate why that warning is needed. **You also will need to set xlim and ylim to be the same.**

```
 plot(1:10);par(new=TRUE)
 plot(10:1)
```

[image]

After reviewing the comments, my vote is for @John's point that a new `plot`-call would perhaps have a different set of xlim and ylim, not to mention the possibility of overwriting all the text objects in the margins. `points` and `lines` do not have the facility to recalculate the limits of the plot area so they are "safe" to use with `plot.default`.

Comment: The question is about why, not how to use it.

Comment: OK, then maybe we should vote to close as off-topic? (I thought the question was about missing functionality. So I suppose the fact that the functionality was there with a different mechanism would be a sort-of answer?)

Comment: Close away, it's actually a dupe of this: http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e4/devel/08/03/0725.html

Comment: So 6 years ago, it was proposed in R-devel and then not acted upon. It had some support from @G.Grothendieck, but never got accepted.