# How to combine two plots in R?

Tags: r, plot, error-handling

I am trying to combine two plots but my code does not work and here is my code.

```
a <- runif(10,1,5)
b <- runif(10,1,5)
c <- runif(10,1,5)
d <- runif(10,1,5)
plot(a,b,pch=2)
plot(c,d,add=TRUE)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: May be this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262017/why-does-plot-not-respect-add-true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `points` function for your second "layer":

```
a <- runif(10,1,5)
b <- runif(10,1,5)
c <- runif(10,1,5)
d <- runif(10,1,5)
plot(a, b, pch=2, xlab = "a | c", ylab = "b | d")
points(c, d, col="blue")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
a <- runif(10,1,5)
b <- runif(10,1,5)
c <- runif(10,1,5)
d <- runif(10,1,5)
plot(a,b,pch=2)
par(new = T)
plot(c,d,add=TRUE, axes= F, xlab=NA,ylab=NA)
axis(4)
```

[image]

Comment: The label and ticks on the left-hand axis may sometimes get messy, but the basic technique works fine.